# Wrong Geopoint field on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, geofirex

I'm actually on a project where I'm using ReactNative and Firebase and I would like to set a geopoint data in Firebase, but when I update the doc on FB I have a wrong type of my data, the Geopoint is a map but I want a geopoint field.

Version in package.json :

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/storage": "^12.8.0",
"geofirex": "^0.1.0",
"rxjs": "^7.5.5",
```

this is my code :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import * as geofirex from 'geofirex';
import RNLocation from 'react-native-location';

const geo = geofirex.init(firebase);
useEffect(() => {
RNLocation.requestPermission({
  ios: 'whenInUse',
  android: {
    detail: 'coarse',
  },
});
this.locationSubscription = RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates(
  locations => {
    const {latitude, longitude} = locations[0];
    setCurrentLocation(locations[0]);
    const location = geo.point(latitude, longitude);
    if (currentUser?.location?.geohash !== location?.geohash) {
      firestore().collection('users').doc(currentUID).update({
        location,
      });
    }
  },
);
}, []);
```

Now I show you the data on my FB :
[image]

But I want data like this (like array not map) :
[image]

I can't find where

I don't understand where the problem comes from and why it changes type !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the react specific implementation, but Firestore does not support geo-query directly, but you can implement it
check this please, how they are doing in other languages,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries